# Can't get the target table by XPath through HTMLAgility Pack in C#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want get the data form the site "WindGuru".

After I copy the `XPath` of my target table by `chrome's` Built-in features.

It throws `NullReferenceException` again and again...

Please, tell me how to solve this problem.

Thank you all. :)

Here is my code fragment...

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData("http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=572782"));


HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(ms, Encoding.ASCII);


HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docWindContext = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
docWindContext.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//*[@id='div_wgfcst1']/table").InnerHtml);
```

Comment: Save your `HtmlDocument` and see what you actually got : `doc.Save("Result.html");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no table after your id.
I guess you are trying to find the json part with all the data?

Try this instead:

```
docWindContext.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//*[@id='div_wgfcst1']/script").InnerHtml);
```

(Change table to script)
Then you will get all the js code i guess you are after.